# Keras functional api explanation of activation() layer?

Tags: keras

With the keras functional api it is possible to write something like this:

```
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = Dense(8, activation='softmax')(x)
```

My question is whether the Activation() function is a separate Layer (equivalent to Dense(128, activation='relu') or if not... why and when this notation is used?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://keras.io/activations/), the activation layer in keras is equivalent to a dense layer with the same activation passed as an argument.

This would be equivalent

```
x = Dense(64)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
```

is equivalent to

```
x = Dense(8, activation='relu')(x)
```

---

As per your example if the activation layer is used as a layer, this will act as a transformation of the outputs of the previous layer.

As you can see in the model

```
inputs = Input(shape=(784,))
x = Dense(32, activation='tanh')(inputs)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(8, activation='softmax')(x)
```

The output of the first layer is the result of a densely connected layer with a tanh function. Then these outputs will each be transformed by a relu function. You can see how this is simply a transformation and does not introduce any new model parameters using

```
model.summary()
```

[image]

Comment: In my case multiple Conv1D Layers are concatenated and then the code above is added: `x = Activation('relu')(x)`
`x = Dense(8, activation='softmax')(x)`  .... does this make any sense? Why should one perform Activation before Dense when there is no Dense Layer before the `Activation` part?

Comment: So `x = Activation('relu')(x)` is only a transformation?

Comment: Yes in this case you would simply be transforming the outputs of the previous layer.